# Canvas background not scaling properly (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, background

I have a background that is compiled of 7 PNG images, but for bigger or smaller screens it will not fit correctly. I have tried numerous ways to fix this issue but can't seem to find out how to fix his issue.

**Expected result when scaling screen**
[image: Expected Result]

**Actual result when scaling screen**
[image: Actual Result]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Please let me know!

*Extra images*

[image: Hills Background]
[image: Canvas Inspector]